# Cannot deploy geoserver.war on Apache Tomcat

Tags: geoserver

I'm very new to this so bear with me. I am trying to deploy geoserver.war through Apache Tomcat, but I keep getting the following page whenever I do:

[image]

I have tried moving geoserver.war into the Tomcat webapps folder, but still continue to get the same problem. How would I go about fixing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two ways to install GeoServer on Windows, either by adding the war file to your existing tomcat install, or using the binary independent distribution (which contains Jetty). What you can't do is mix and match these approaches.